# Интеграция Юкасса+aiogram

Tags: python

Скажите пожалуйста, сталкивался-ли кто-нибудь с подключением рекурентных платежей от юкасса в ТГ боте на aiogram?
Как реализовать автоплатёж? Спасибо!

Comment: [Автоплатежи в ЮKassa](https://yookassa.ru/docs/support/payments/extra/autopayment), [Автоплатежи — Прием платежей по API ЮKassa](https://yookassa.ru/developers/payment-acceptance/scenario-extensions/recurring-payments)

Comment: Нашли ли вы решение данного вопроса? Сейчас занимаюсь им и не могу найти ответ

Comment: Да, решил эту задачу. Но решить её можно только если оплата происходит по ссылке, без привлечения send_invoice